# Why is my code to traverse binary tree in-order only recording the value of the first node?

Tags: python, recursion, tree

I am trying to write code to traverse a Binary tree in-order using recursion, here is my code:

e.g. input = [1,null,2,3]

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.left = left
#         self.right = right

class Solution:
    def inorderTraversal(self, root: TreeNode) -> List[int]:
        in_order = []
        stack, curr = [], root

        if not curr: 
            return None
        else:
            inorderTraversal(curr.left)
            in_order.append(curr.val)
            inorderTraversal(curr.right)

        return in_order
```

For some reason, the output is only recording the value of the first node! So I am getting `in_order=[1]` I suspect it is something to do with the code inside the `'else'` statement. Can anyone suggest modifications? Thanks

As a follow on, based on the solutions provided:

For the following [Binary tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGTFk.jpg)

I want to make sure I understand it correctly, the recursive stack will store A, then B, then C. Since C has no child (we hit the base case). C is then recorded in `in_order`. Then we pop the next item off the recursive stack which is B,at this point do we call on `inorderTraversal(root.left)` or `inorderTraversal(root.right)`?

More generally, when we pop things off the recursion stack, do we start from the first recursive call and work downwards?
How does the computer process it? I understand how objects are added to the recursion stack, but the confusion is when they are popped off, where do we start from? Because the way I read it is that the recursive stack that holds A,B,C is from `inorderTraversal(root.left)`, so that means when they get popped off we should move down to the next line `in_order.append(root.val)` ; is this right?

Comment: You are not passing the dictionaries around with you.  So each recursive calls gets its own in_order variable.  So you append to it, but it's in no way combining with the other in_order variables in the other calls.  You either need to pass in your in_order function and append to it, or return a list and append/extend the list after each recursive call.

Comment: I see! Instead of dictionary, do you mean list? Because in_order is a list

Comment: When you say 'pass in your in_order function', do you mean make it an argument in the function? If so can you show how to do this please? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, sorry, I mean list. And yes, I mean passing them as arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options for this.  You can either pass in an array into your recursive function that you append to.  Or you can return an array and combine it with the calling function's.  The first is probably more performant because you aren't moving the same elements over and over.  But it's not quite as pretty.  Using your code above, here's a suggested change.

```
class Solution:
    def inorderTraversal(self, root: TreeNode) -> List[int]:
        in_order = []
        if not root: 
            return []
        else:
            in_order.extend(self.inorderTraversal(root.left))
            in_order.append(root.val)
            in_order.extend(self.inorderTraversal(root.right))

        return in_order
```

**UPDATE**

To walk through the Tree in your OP, here's what the calls would look like.  I'm going to shorten the function call to R() for brevity and I'll simply refer to a tree by it's value.  Indentations will symbolize the depth of the recursion stack.

```
R(A)
  R(B) # A.left
     R(C) # B.left
        R(C.left)
           return []
        Append(C)
        R(.right)
           return []
        return [C]    # R(C.left) + [C] + R(C.right)
     Append(B)
     R(D) # B.right
        R(E)  # D.left
        Append(D)
        R(D.right)  
           return []
        return [E, D]      # R(D.left) + [D] + R(D.right)
     return [C, B, E, D]   # R(B.left) + [B] + R(B.right)
  Append(A)
  R(G)  # A.right
      ...

   return [C, B, E, D, A, F, G, H]  # R(A.left) + [A] + R(A.right)
```

Comment: Hi Saquintes, thanks for the answer. One more question, am I right in saying that the each time we pop and element off the recursion stack, we run through each of the three lines in the 'else' statement for that node?

Comment: that is correct...though I'm not completely sure what "element" you are talking about popping.  But each recursive function invocation will go through all three calls for each TreeNode instance that it was called with (assuming it's not None)

Comment: Thanks Saquintes, this makes complete sense. But if what you say is true (and of course I believe it is), can you look at the Binary Tree link in my question. So, if we apply the recursion to the Binary tree, we start with [A,B,C] in the recursion stack. C gets popped out and added to in_order. Then B is next, but THIS IS WHERE I STRUGGLE, because if we invoke the three calls, by invoking the first one, won't we go back down to C??

Comment: I'm not sure I would think about it in terms of a recursive stack for the variables as much as a recursive stack for the function, personally.  Might be what's causing the confusion.  But it could be that you don't start with a recursion stack of [A, B, C].  You start with an empty stack.  Then you push R(A) on.  Then R(A) pushes R(B) on.  Then R(B) pushes R(C) on.  Then nothing is added, so it returns out and R(B) pushes on R(D), etc.  I've tried to address this more visually in an update.

Answer (score 2):

You are not using the result of the recursive call (common mistake). The other answer has you covered on that. You could do this very elegantly with a generator function, however:

```
class Solution:
    def inorderTraversal(self, root: TreeNode) -> List[int]:
        def io(node):
            if node: 
                yield from io(node.left)
                yield node.val
                yield from io(node.right)

        return list(io(root))
```

Comment: Nice.  This is better than extending the array.  I was trying to change his code minimally as it's not how I would personally have set it up, but this fixes the potential performance issue.

Comment: @saquintes I am not sold on any performance gain. One would have to benchmark it. I have found lists and their operations are often quite fast, as they are heavily C-optimzed, whereas generators with their repeated calls to next can be laborious. But ultimately both these recursive approaches will stink compared to a purely iterative implementation without any change of function context :-)
I just like this for its cleanliness.

Comment: Yes profiling would be the best/only way to tell and should be done if this was production code needing to be as fast as possible.  It could also be dependant on tree size, which you'd have to find out in profiling.